# Split Multiple Comma separated columns to Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Please Help.

I am trying to split several comma separated values per customer Id, i have this working for a single column but the tricky part is applying this to several columns

e.g. 
Source

```
Cust Id | Value 1 | Value 2
1       | 3,4     | a2,a3
2       | 1,2,3   | a1,a3,a5
```

Required Out

```
Cust Id | Value 1 | Value 2
1       | 3       | a2
1       | 4       | a3
2       | 1       | a1 
2       | 2       | a3 
2       | 3       | a5
```

I have attempted using a lookup table which contains a single integer column populated from 1 - 100 which should be the max amount of separated values. I then used this in the below query to split out the values which works fine but just for one column

```
SELECT ID, TRIM(Mid(',' & Value1 & ',',[Entries]+1,Instr([Entries]+1,',' & Value1 & ',',',')-([Entries]+1))) AS Split
FROM MyTable
WHERE Entries=Instr(Entries,',' & Value1 & ',',',') And Entries<len(',' & Value1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to loop across the columns, picking up the Cust ID numbers, and splitting "Value 1" and "Value 2" into arrays. You then write them according to the counts of how many per ID to a separate sheet. That would be the rough logic to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi Davy, thanks for the quick response. I have tried implementing a loop which i have working for a single column, but i am struggling to apply this over the several columns. my vba isnt the best so any code snippets of looping across columns would be much apreciated.

Comment: Why not post what you have tried in the original post?  This will give us a starting point to help.

Comment: As Scott says, I'm happy to give you pointers if you show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the count of commas in `Value 1` and `Value 2` fields are the same, here is an idea:

```
'needs reference to MS ActiveX Data Objects xxx Library
Sub SplitData()

Dim oRst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String, oVars1 As Variant, oVars2 As Variant
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_SplitData

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Customers;"

Set oRst = New ADODB.Recordset
With oRst
    'open recordset
    .Open sSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    'fill-in recordset
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    'loop through the records in Customers table
    Do While Not .EOF
        'split data
        oVars1 = Split(.Fields("Value1").Value, ",")
        oVars2 = Split(.Fields("Value2").Value, ",")
        'loop through the splited data
        For i = 0 To UBound(oVars1)
            'improve this piece of code
            '
            'only for example - print data
            Debug.Print .Fields("CustID"), oVars1(i), oVars2(i)

        Next
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

Exit_SplitData:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oRst = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_SplitData:
    MsgBox Err.Number, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_SplitData

End Sub
```

Comment: I have updated the question as suggested, apologies. Thanks Maciej, yes the number of commas in each column should be the same. I will try the above suggestion and let you know how i get on. Thank you all for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Maciej' answer looks good, but as I had already worked on an answer for you, I will go ahead and post it anyway:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FncCreateOutput()

    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim custID As Long
    Dim value1Str As Variant
    Dim value2Str As Variant

    Sheets("Input").Select

    'We start at row two as this is a header line
    rowCount = 2

    Do While Range("A" & rowCount).Value <> ""

        'Reselect the Input sheet - it will have been deselected by previous calls to 'FncWriteIDValues()'
        Sheets("Input").Select

        custID = Range("A" & rowCount).Value
        value1Str = Split(Range("B" & rowCount).Value, ",")
        value2Str = Split(Range("C" & rowCount).Value, ",")

        'You need to check that you have the same count of values in the two variant arrays
        If UBound(value1Str) <> UBound(value2Str) Then

            Stop

        Else

            'They match so we can now pass this information to a function that will write to another sheet
            Call FncWriteIDValues(custID, value1Str, value2Str)

        End If
        rowCount = rowCount + 1

    Loop

End Sub

Private Function FncWriteIDValues(id As Long, val1 As Variant, val2 As Variant)

    Dim totalRows As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Sheets("Output").Select

    'Get the total rows in the 'Ouput' sheet used so far
    totalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

    Do While i <= UBound(val1)

        Range("A" & totalRows + 1).Value = id
        Range("B" & totalRows + 1).Value = val1(i)
        Range("c" & totalRows + 1).Value = val2(i)
        i = i + 1
        totalRows = totalRows + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

You create two sheets in Excel, one called "Input" and one called "Output". In your "Input" sheet, put the header and data, and in the "Output", just the header line in row 1. The code will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks again for the mentioned suggestions, wasnt expecting such a quick response. I have managed to implement Maciej code and its working perfectly.#

Comment: Don't forget to mark Maciej's answer as correct if it answered your question.